# I would like to know if raf ah alyadayn is authentic

Tags: salat, fiqh

Assalamu alaikum,
I live in Bangladesh. In our area, most of the imaams follow imaam **Abu Hanifa's** madhab. They don't perform "rafah alyadayn" (raising hands) in salah.

I just wanted to know if it is authentic or not.

Comment: http://islamqa.info/en/21439

Answer (score 1):

After Rukooh, aka, after saying "sami Allah huliman hamida" raising the hands, it's not a must. It's a Sunnah, it's a Mustahab, meaning appreciated, supported, encouraged. It's not a must. If you don't do it, your Salah will be complete. But if you do, it's better, because our Prophet said, "pray (Salah) as you see me pray". So following the Prophet on this part, aka, your question, is Mustahab, not a Wajib or Fard. Hope this helps.